# Calculating Retention/ Churn Using SQL

Tags: sql, amazon-athena

I've created a derived table that should be pretty close to calculating churn, but can't seem to get the final answer

```
account_id     current_month_paid     last_month_paid    next_month_paid
 633               2018-10                NULL                NULL
 862               2018-10                NULL              2018-11
 862               2018-11               2018-10            2018-12
 862               2018-12               2018-11            2019-01
1448               2018-10                NULL              2018-11
```

How can I group these columns so that I get retention % per month, like:

```
2018-10       2018-11       2018-12
  92%          94%            93%
```

Any help would be appreciated. I'm using AWS Athena in case it matters

EDIT: These are sample percentages, they aren't actual calculations. Im looking to group by month and show what % had a previous month paid (per account ID)

Comment: Please explain the logic for your calculations.  It is entirely unclear how you get those percentages from 5 rows of data.

Comment: those are sample calculations, sorry!

Answer (score 0):

The semantics of your derived table is not quite clear to me but assuming that

- last_month_paid = null for a new user in the given month, and
- next_month_paid = null means a user has their last payment in the given month I'd go with something like:

```
WITH paying_user_stats AS (
    SELECT
        account_id,
        current_month_paid,
        1 as paying_users,
        case when last_month_paid is null then 1 else 0 end as paying_users_new,
        case when next_month_paid is null then 1 else 0 end as paying_users_churn
    FROM accounts
)
SELECT
    current_month_paid,
    sum(paying_users) as paying_users,
    sum(paying_users-paying_users_new) as paying_users_month_begin,
    sum(paying_users-paying_users_churn) as paying_users_month_end,
    sum(paying_users_new) as paying_users_new,
    sum(paying_users_churn) as paying_users_churn
FROM paying_user_stats
GROUP BY current_month_paid
```

Now, if I understand your definition of retention rate right, you are looking for `sum(paying_users)/sum(paying_users_month_begin)`. You may want to do that division outside of your query in your BI tool, Spreadsheet, etc., to avoid issues such as accidentally aggregating this to unweighted averages.